# Python Palindrome error

Tags: python, python-2.7, palindrome

This is my solution to the problem: whether given string can be permuted to form a palindrome or not . I get correct for very few text cases. For the given case it prints YES even though it should print NO

```
string = "cdefghmnopqrstuvw"

found = False

count = 0
for i in string:
if string.count('i') % 2 == 0:
    found = True
else:
    count += 1

if count > 1:
    found = False

if not found:
    print("NO")
else:
    print("YES")
```

Comment: You are counting if the character `'i'`, not the character referenced by the variable `i`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters How am I supposed to modify that error ?

Comment: You could use `string.count(i)` instead, but that'd be inefficient at best. Counting requires a loop through the string, so for each character you do a full loop, making this a quadratic algorithm. Using `Counter()` as shown in the answers is far more efficient as it only needs to loop through your text once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A string can be permuted to a palindrome, if when it has even length, it has only even number of occurrences for its letters, or if when has odd length, all letters but one has even number of occurrences. So the following will work:

```
from collections import Counter
def can_be_palindrome(s):
    return sum(v % 2 for v in Counter(s).values()) == len(s) % 2
```

With the `sum` we count the number of letters with odd number of occurrences. `len(s) % 2` will have value `0` if `s` has even length and `1` if it has odd length.

Examples:

```
>>> can_be_palindrome("aab")
True
>>> can_be_palindrome("abbb")
False
>>> can_be_palindrome("abcabc")
True
```

Comment: Right, I missed the *permuted* part.

Comment: @JuniorCompressor You forgot the `return` keyword in your function.